# Changing the TD value during onclick

Tags: php, jquery, css, html-table

Below is my HTML:

```
          <form method="post" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <table class="table table-condensed1" >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                 <td><span><?php echo $row['Admin_Email'];?></span> <input type="text" name="email" size="30" autocomplete="off" class="hidden"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name </td>
                 <td><span><?php echo $row['Admin_Name'];?></span> <input type="text" name="name" size="30" autocomplete="off" class="hidden"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                 <td><span><?php echo $row['Admin_Gender'];?></span> <input type="text" name="gend" size="10" autocomplete="off" class="hidden"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >Date of Birth</td>
                 <td><span><?php echo $row['Admin_DOB'];?></span> <input type="date" name="dob" autocomplete="off" class="hidden"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >Contact Number</td>
                 <td><span><?php echo $row['Admin_ContactNum'];?></span> <input type="text" name="num" size="15" autocomplete="off" class="hidden"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                 <td><span><?php echo $row['Admin_Address'];?></span> <input type="text" name="add" size="100" autocomplete="off" class="hidden"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</form>
```

The CSS code to hide `class="hidden"` textbox:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

My jQuery to change the edit to save and show an input text box, and then show a notification bar when the user has clicked on save:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".table").on("click", ".edit", function() {
    var prevTD = $(this).parent().prev();
    var value = prevTD.find("span").hide().text();
    prevTD.find("input").show().val(value);
    $(this).toggleClass("edit save").text("Save");
}).on("click", ".save", function() {
    var prevTD = $(this).parent().prev();
    var value = prevTD.find("input").hide().val();
    prevTD.find("span").show().text(value);
    $(this).toggleClass("edit save").text("Edit");

$("form").submit(function() { $(this).find("input").show(); }); 




    jNotify(
    '<img src="../Images/success.png" height="15px"/> Profile updated!',
    {
      autoHide : true, 
      MinWidth: 150,
      TimeShown : 2500,
      OpacityOverlay : 0 ,
      HorizontalPosition : 'right',
      VerticalPosition: 'bottom'
    })



});


});

</script>
```

My PHP code to update my member table:

```
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $gend = $_POST["gend"];
    $dob = $_POST["dob"];
    $num  = $_POST["num"];
    $address1 = $_POST["add"];




mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE admin SET Admin_Email ='$email' , Admin_Name='$name', Admin_Gender='$gend', Admin_DOB='$dob', Admin_ContactNum='$num', Admin_Address='$address1' WHERE Admin_ID=$id");
```

I am unable to retrieve the text entered in `<input type="text" name="name" size="30" autocomplete="off" class="hidden">`. How do I retrieve this text? I want to get the text and declare in my php where I can do `$name = $_POST["name"];` and update my table in the database.

Comment: Take a look at the `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: I want it to be editable only when I click on the edit button

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just a heads up - assume you will be writing all of the code yourself. We don't hand out code around here very often, but we WILL point you in the right direction. I strongly suggest that you edit the question to ask for advice on the *approach*, instead of the code. (Our main reason for that...if you don't write the code yourself, you won't actually learn anything.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for suggesting. I have already edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with help of **[`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)** attribute

```js
$('.table tr>td a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this)
    .closest('tr')
    // get the table row
    .find('td:eq(1)')
    // get second column
    .prop('contenteditable', $(this).text() == 'Edit')
    // setting td as editable
    .focus()
    // focusing the td
    .end().end()
    // back to button
    .text($(this).text() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit');
    // update button text
});
```

```css
.table-condensed1 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table-condensed1 td {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.table-condensed1 td:first-child {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.table-condensed1 td:last-child,
.table-condensed1 td:last-child a {
  color: #0078b0;
}
.table-condensed1 td:last-child,
.table-condensed1 td:last-child a:hover {
  color: #2ba6cb;
  background-color: white;
}
.table-condensed1 > thead > tr > th,
.table-condensed1 > tbody > tr > th,
.table-condensed1 > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-condensed1 > thead > tr > td,
.table-condensed1 > tbody > tr > td,
.table-condensed1 > tfoot > tr > td {
  border-top: 0px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-bottom-width: thin;
  padding: 10px;
}
.table-condensed1 tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row[ "Admin_Email"];?>
      </td>
      <td><a href="">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row[ "Admin_Name"];?>
      </td>
      <td><a href="">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row[ "Admin_Gender"];?>
      </td>
      <td><a href="">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date of Birth</td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row[ "Admin_DOB"];?>
      </td>
      <td><a href="">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contact Number</td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row[ "Admin_ContactNum"];?>
      </td>
      <td><a href="">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row[ "Admin_Address"];?>
      </td>
      <td><a href="#top">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, where do I put this into my code? $('.table tr>td a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').prop('contenteditable', $(this).text() == 'Edit').focus().end().end().text($(this).text() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit');

});

Answer (score 0):

Put a span containing normal text and an input that the user can edit in the TD. When the user clicks on the edit button, hide the span, show the input, and change the class and text of the button. Go vice versa when they click on the save button.

```js
$(".table").on("click", ".edit", function() {
  var prevTD = $(this).parent().prev();
  var value = prevTD.find("span").hide().text();
  prevTD.find("input").show().val(value);
  $(this).toggleClass("edit save").text("Save");
}).on("click", ".save", function() {
  var prevTD = $(this).parent().prev();
  var value = prevTD.find("input").hide().val();
  prevTD.find("span").show().text(value);
  $(this).toggleClass("edit save").text("Edit");
});
// Unhide all the hidden inputs when submitting the form
$("form").submit(function() { 
    $(this).find("input").show(); 
});
```

```css
.table-condensed1 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table-condensed1 td {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.table-condensed1 td:first-child {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.table-condensed1 td:last-child,
.table-condensed1 td:last-child a {
  color: #0078b0;
}
.table-condensed1 td:last-child,
.table-condensed1 td:last-child a:hover {
  color: #2ba6cb;
  background-color: white;
}
.table-condensed1 > thead > tr > th,
.table-condensed1 > tbody > tr > th,
.table-condensed1 > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-condensed1 > thead > tr > td,
.table-condensed1 > tbody > tr > td,
.table-condensed1 > tfoot > tr > td {
  border-top: 0px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-bottom-width: thin;
  padding: 10px;
}
.table-condensed1 tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td><span>Admin_Email</span>
        <input type="text" class="hidden">
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><span>Admin_Name</span>
        <input type="text" class="hidden">
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td><span>Admin_Gender</span>
        <input type="text" class="hidden">
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date of Birth</td>
      <td><span>Admin_DOB</span>
        <input type="text" class="hidden">
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contact Number</td>
      <td><span>Admin_ContactNum</span>
        <input type="text" class="hidden">
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td><span>Admin_Address</span>
        <input type="text" class="hidden">
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure what you did wrong. I just converted my answer to an executable snippet, and it works fine.

Comment: Hi, I have did this successfully. But I have another question based on the same thing. Can you assist me further? I can't post any question anymore.

Comment: How do I approach you?

Comment: You can edit your question, and add your updated code to the end of the question.

Comment: Hi. Can you please help me ?

Comment: The problem is that form fields are not submitted if they're hidden with `display: none`, which is what `.hide()` does.

Comment: Try adding a `.submit()` handler to the form that calls `$(this).find("input").show()`

Comment: Like how? Can you give me an example? And I think the another problem is I can't submit the form when the EDIT and SAVE are not submit button

Comment: `$("form").submit(function() { $(this).find("input").show(); });`. How hard is that?

Comment: which mean I can declare it like
$name = $("form").submit(function() { $(this).find("input").show(); });.  ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do there. My code is Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: It just makes submitting the form include the `name` input (and all the other inputs), so you can get it from `$_POST['name']`. It seems like you're very confused about how Javascript and PHp work.

Comment: Ok. so I just paste `$("form").submit(function() { $(this).find("input").show(); });` after the jquery that you have done for me earlier.

And then where do I put my php code? in the jquery ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it should be.

Comment: Hi, after adding the $("form").submit(function() { $(this).find("input").show(); });.  I am still unable to call the input that insert in the hidden textbox. Can you please explain to me how it should be done?

Comment: It turns out I was wrong that form fields that are hidden with CSS don't get submitted. So I don't know why you're not getting the form fields submitted.

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with your server script. I suggest you create a new question and post the server script there.